# Pydroid 3 насколько он мощный

Tags: python, pydroid

Столкнулся с проблемой чёрного екрана есть робочий код ошибок никаких не выдает, но вместо вывода на екран всего кода у меня просто чёрный екран не пойму в чем проблема

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

W,H = 720, 1500

display = pygame.display.set_mode((W, H))

Red = (255, 0, 0)

def push(but):
    keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if but.x < mouse[0] < but.x+but.w:
        if but.y < mouse[1] < but.y+but.h:
            if keys[0] == 1:
                return True
                
                
y=W//2
y=H//2
speed=3


up = pygame.Rect((250, 1100), (200, 100))
down = pygame.Rect((250, 1200), (200, 100))
left = pygame.Rect((50, 1200), (150, 100))
right = pygame.Rect((500, 1200), (150, 100))

while True:
    display.fill((120,120,120))
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
            
pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 255, 0)(x, y), 50) 





if push(up):
    y-=speed
elif push(down):
    y+=speed
elif push(left):
   x-=speed
elif push(right):
   x+=speed
        
        
   if x - 50 < 0:
       x = 50
   elif x + 50 > 720:
       x = 720-50
   elif y - 50 < 0:
       y = 50
   elif + 50 >1500:
       y = 1500-50
        
        
display.fill((Red), up)
display.fill((Red), down)
display.fill((Red), left)
display.fill((Red), right)
pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Видимо ваш код просто ничего не делает. Черный экран в pydroid — это просто пустая консоль. Если в конце у вас не выводится строчка [program finished], то значит в программе где-то бесконечный цикл.

Comment: И покажите ваш код.

Comment: Если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его галочкой как принятый.

Answer (score 3):

Ну, в коде много ошибок. Первая и главная — все ваши изменения экрана проходят вне главного цикла (у вас неправильно расставлены отступы) и поэтому программа просто до них не доходит, а бесконечно выполняет ничего не делающий `while True`. Помимо этого в программе есть много мелких ошибок (где-то запятая пропущена, где-то вместо `x` стоит `y`) и несоответствий стилю. Вот исправленный код:

```
import pygame

def push(but):
    keys = pygame.mouse.get_pressed() 
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if but.x < mouse[0] < but.x + but.w:
        if but.y < mouse[1] < but.y + but.h:
            if keys[0] == 1:
                return True
                                
pygame.init()
width, height = 720, 1500
display = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
Red = (255, 0, 0)
up = pygame.Rect((250, 1100), (200, 100))
down = pygame.Rect((250, 1200), (200, 100))
left = pygame.Rect((50, 1200), (150, 100))
right = pygame.Rect((500, 1200), (150, 100))
x = width // 2
y = height // 2
speed = 3

while True:
    for ev in pygame.event.get():
        if ev.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
    display.fill((120, 120, 120))
    pygame.draw.circle(display, (0, 255, 0), (x, y), 50) 
    if push(up):
        y -= speed
    elif push(down):
        y += speed
    elif push(left):
       x -= speed
    elif push(right):
       x += speed    
    if x - 50 < 0:
        x = 50
    elif x + 50 > 720:
        x = 720 - 50
    elif y - 50 < 0:
        y = 50
    elif + 50 > 1500:
        y = 1500 - 50 
    display.fill((Red), up)
    display.fill((Red), down)
    display.fill((Red), left)
    display.fill((Red), right)
    pygame.display.update()
```